# ViewBag persist with load balanced server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, load-balancing

Will my ViewBag stay around on a load balanced server?

Example:

```
C# --> groupid = 5;
C# --> ViewBag.groupid = groupid;
Razor View page -->  @Html.Hidden("groupid", (Int32)@ViewBag.groupid)
```

Comment: No. `ViewBag` is for passing a value from the controller to the view. As soon has the method has returned the view the controller is disposed.

Comment: When 2 servers have identical code and the C# has a variable in memory of say "5" and it is passed from the method to one of the servers to render the view and so to me it would seem that it would pass it along to either server.   So sure a session variable used in the way which stores it in sql server would work,   but the normal session variable would obviously be the worst as it would be on 1 server and then just then a passing of it to another server it would not get passed as it does not know about it.

Comment: Ok, so then based on my comment above, since the Viewbag is dynamic is nature, at what point is the value gone?  Is it like the Session in that it really is completely server based?

Comment: Web Forms has a way to have a web.config value that forces the application to stay on the same server, or be sticky.   MVC have this ?

Comment: You last comment is talking about session, but your question is about `ViewBag`! And what is the point of your code anyway - `groupid` has a value so why are you adding a `ViewBag` property so you can set the value of the hidden input to exactly the same value it already is? It just needs to be `@Html.Hidden("groupid")` or better `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.groupid)`

Comment: true  thank you Stephen